# ASP.NET Core Web API does not work on server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2. It was deployed on a server that had .NET Framework 4.7.2 installed along with the Hosting Bundle 2.2.8. It worked on that configuration. We are using Entity Framework for .NET in our application to access the database, hence the 4.7.2 target.

The client is forcing us to remove all old versions of .NET Framework and install the ASP.NET Core Runtime 8.0.0 with the corresponding Hosting Bundle.

With this in place, our Web API is no longer working. The error we are getting when accessing the Swagger page is this:

> 500 - Internal server error.
> There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Here is the `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="TavisEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TavisEntityModel.csdl|res://*/TavisEntityModel.ssdl|res://*/TavisEntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=NN.NNN.NN.NN;initial catalog=MyCatalog;persist security info=True;user id=MyUser;password=MyPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
            <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath=".\MyWebApi.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Accessing the application through IIS (click on the binding link shown at the right hand side menu), the browser pops up on `https://localhost:444` (that the port in the binding) but this screen is shown:

[image]

What is the reason for this error and how do we solve it?

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: ASP.NET Core is not the same as ASP.NET Framework. Uninstalling it was a bit of a wrong decision. ASP.NET Framework 4.7.2 is still valid ad supported. You should either install it back or refactor you project to NET Core 8. Se [EOF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework).

Comment: @IonUrsachi - The application has everything it needs to be able to run. If I run the "MyWebApi.exe" directly from the deployment folder (so outside IIS), I see it running when accessing on localhost:5000, which is where it listens by default. That is not the issue. .NET 8.0.0 is the latest Core implementation and it supports both types of applications (the ones targeting .Net Framework 4.x and the ones targeting any flavour of .Net Core. My web.config file is missing something that is now required when hosting the web application in IIS using the Hosting Bundle that comes with .NET 8.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve the issue. It was a simple matter of "repairing" the installation of the Microsoft .NET 8.0.0. - Windows Hosting Server bundle. I have seen that being suggested on other SO tickets where a similar problem was reported. After that, I was able to open the web.config file in IIS and with a restart of the website, now my Web API is responding.